# Java: can 2 threads run the same unsynchronized method on an object truly concurrently?

Tags: concurrency

I have 2 situations:

Situation 1: there are 2 threads, which share ONE instance of a class having a doSomething() method. 
Situation 2: there are 2 threads, each has one instance of a class having doSomething() method.

```
void doSomething() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
```

When the 2 threads start, they both invoke the doSomething(). Look at the output, I can't see the difference between situation 1 and 2.

The output for the 2 threads (thread A and B ) is something like this: A A A A B B B A A B B B B ....

Can you tell me the difference in CONCURRENCY between situation 1 and 2? Many thanks!

Comment: That method should be `static` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to see the difference for a situation like the above since the operation doesn't affect any state variables (instance variables). Try a method like this:

```
class C {
 int i = 0;
 synchronized void doSomething() {
  while(i < 20) {
   System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : Value for i=" + i );
   i++;
  }
 }
}
```

If you run the above using 2 separate objects, each one of the threads will print 20 values (from 0 to 19).
If you run the above using 2 threads sharing the same object, **OVERALL** the 2 threads will print 20 values but it's uncertain which thread will print what values since you can't predict which thread will get to increment the `i` value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have test your code with 2 threads and 1 object. However,only 1 thread prints the values from 0 to 19. The other thread doesn't do anything because at that time, i is 20. I have to add one more line outside the while loop : i = 0; to reset the value of i to 0 and then I see what you mean. Anyway, your code gave me the idea of what I want to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's only a difference between the two situations if the threads are touching member data of the object's they're running on.

With two threads and two objects, you'll see them both running independently.

With two threads and one object, you'll see them interfering with each other, overwriting each other's values in the member variables. This is known as a race condition, and is a giant pain to find and debug because it's intermittent. Dealing with two threads sharing variables is the reason things like semaphores and the lock statement exist.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.

Except for the `synchronized` keyword, threads don't care about instances.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably suspected, there is no difference from a concurrency point of view.